# Open HTML file in same Chrome app window?

Tags: javascript, css, json, html, google-chrome-app

Aloha,

I am trying to a make a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) that replaces the Chrome Dev Editor. Here is what I have currently:

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
chrome.app.window.create('backstage.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
        'width': 1036,
        'height': 583
    }
  }); 
});
```

backstage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Celestia Pro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "material.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "material.min.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- The drawer is always open in large screens. The header is always shown,
  even in small screens. -->
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer
            mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
                  mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
               for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </label>
        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample"
                 id="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content">
<style>
.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  width: 100%;
}
.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title {
  color: #fff;
  height: 176px;
  background: url('welcome-card.jpg') center / cover;
}
.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__menu {
  color: #fff;
}

div.start-cards {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
</style>

<div class="start-cards" align = center>
<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome to Celestia Pro</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    Celestia Pro is a new integrated development environment (IDE) that allows developers to create Chrome apps quickly and efficiently. We're still in our baby stages, but we hope this tool works for you.
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" onclick="runWizard()">
      Get Started
    </a>
    <script>

    </script>
  </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
  </main>
</div>
</div>
    <script src = "./material.min.js">
    <script src = "./material.js">

</body>
</html>
```

This seems all fine and dandy until I try to make the **Get Started** button I mention actually open something. I want it to open a page called 'backstage2.html', but no matter what combination I try, it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have tried.

- The `<a href="">` method
- Using the [chrome.app.window.current and/or chrome.app.window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) script by adding a script to the button ("runWizard()")

None of these seem to work. I want to be able to open backstage2.html in the same Chrome app windows! How can I do this, if it is even possible? Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use web components and import the file in your main file. Then you can use it as regular web component. 
Other option is to send the request to the background page where you can hold a reference to opened window. This reference has `contentWindow` property which is a JavaScript's `window` object. You can use it to replace the content of man window (after you read new file data using e.g. fetch).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`webview`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) into `backstage.html` *(or in a new window)*.

Could be...

**`backstage.html`**:

```
<a id="wizard" class="···">Get Started</a>
<!-- onclick doesn't work by CSP (see note bellow) ··· -->
<webview></webview>
<!-- ··· -->
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

**`main.js`**:

```
onload = function {
  // ···
  document.querySelector('#wizard').addEventListener('click', runWizard);
  // ···
};
// ···
function runWizard() {
  // ···
  document.querySelector('webview').src = 'backstage2.html';
  // ···
};
```

**CSP** -Content Security Policy-, note:
"[You can’t use inline scripting](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy)..."

@abarisone: Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use href ="your html file" target = "_self"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For the future, please try and explain your answer in some detail. Also, read up on [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on Stack Overflow, and wrap your code in code tags. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information as well.

Comment: This will open a link in a browser and it isn't the answer for author's question. Moreover you can't open app's file in a chrome tab so it will not work.